# Get current category id for use in shortcode

Tags: wordpress, categories, shortcode

I need get current category id for use in shortcode, i am trying this but is wrong.

```
$category_current = get_the_category($post->ID) ; echo do_shortcode('[dt-postwall    postwalltype="masonry" category="'.get_the_category($post->ID).'"]
```

Can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

get_the_category, returns Array of Category Objects.
So you need to do following

```
$category_current = get_the_category($post->ID) ; 
echo do_shortcode('[dt-postwall    postwalltype="masonry" category="'.$category_current[0]->name.'"]
```

if you want category slug
$category_current[0]->slug
$category_current[0]->term_id

Answer (score 0):

Works fine but only show the first image, i don´t know why, when i disable category="'.$category_current[0]->name.'"  all posts are displayed